# React 16 fails with error instructing me to use an array of objects instead of an object, but I already am

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm not sure in what way I'm not in compliance with the rendering rules of React. The following worked in React 15.5, but fails in React 16. I haven't been able to find any documentation as to why or any way to correct it.

**I'm getting this error:**

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, key, ref, _owner, _context, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

**My code to build the array:**

(The `<List>` item is from [React-List-Select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-list-select))

```
 render() {
    let listItemArray = [];
    if (myList) {
      myList.map(item=> listItemArray.push(
        <MyItem key={item.uuid} item={item} {...actions} />
        ));
      //  Else, push a <br /> tag to fill the space
    }
    return (
      <List ref={(ref) => this.innerRef = ref} tabIndex="-1"  items={listItemArray} selected={currentItemIndex} multiple={false} onChange={console.log.bind(console)} />
    )
  }
```

The contents of the `listItemArray` appear as follows on inspection:

[image]

Comment: what is the shape of ```myList``` is it an array?

Comment: Great question. It's an array of objects.

Comment: So you're declaring ```listItem``` array and then pushing to ```listItemArray``` what am i missing here? I feel like it would help with more of the example available =)

Comment: What always helps me a ton is creating the most bare bones example in code sandbox. I often find that when i do this the problem becomes very clear. It also gives the SO community something to poke at... It's much easier than having to pull bits of my own code and try to ask a question here out of context. You know what i mean? Just a thought.

Comment: I realized I had a typo. The array names are `myList` and `listItemArray`. `myList` is an array of objects with properties from a database. `listItemArray` is an array of React element objects.

Comment: I find sandboxing to be very helpful too. Unfortunately because the issue may be because I fundamentally misunderstand React 16 vs 15.5 and the issue may be related to the package I'm using, it's hard to sandbox. If I understood the nature of the issue better I would probably find a way to sandbox to determine the exact issue, but I'm not even sure what React is complaining about here since I seem to be doing what it asks and it worked in React 15.5

Comment: Yeah... I feel ya. When i first glanced at your example, the spread you're using ```{...actions}``` jumped out at me as a possible culprit for the object warning but without seeing more of the code I'm just kinda stabbing in the dark.

Comment: That was a good thought regarding the `{...actions}`. Unfortunately removing it did not make a difference.

Comment: Do you have a repo for this app I can clone and take a look at?

Comment: Alas I do not and can't think of a way to add any more meaningful context to my example above. I was hoping this would be one of those things where someone could just tell me I was misunderstanding some basic concept. The issue seems to be related to passing an array of objects as a property. I'll continue to investigate down that line. Thanks very much for your help @archae0pteryx

Comment: Sorry i couldn't be of more help. Cheers mate.